# LDD: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdl.so: version `LIBC' not found (required by ./libNative.so)

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, ldd, android-native-library, linux-native-library

I want to use native library `.SO` files from APK that I extracted. After fixing many errors, I found this one that I didn't understand.

```
./libNative.so: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdl.so: version `LIBC' not found (required by ./libNative.so)
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x0000ffffac13f000)
        libm.so => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so (0x0000ffffac034000)
        libdl.so => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdl.so (0x0000ffffabf1d000)
        libc.so => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so (0x0000ffffabeff000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000ffffabda6000)
        /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x0000ffffac114000)
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It's missing dependency. You can install with a package manager of os you use, like

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6
```

make sure you install correct version of it though.

Comment: but when i run `apt-get install libc6`, it says `libc6 is already the newest version (2.27-3ubuntu1).`. and when i tried the ldd again, its still the same, even after `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: try ldd -v libNative.so  You need correct version of it I suspect

Comment: tried it, and the only error is  `libdl.so (LIBC) => not found`